# Why isn't Kate Bush's "Running Up That Hill" mentioned in the credits at the end of the "Stranger Things" episode?

Tags: soundtrack, credits, stranger-things

In Season 4, Epsisode 4... when Max is spellbound by the very evil Vecna, in an attempt to break the spell, the gang of kids place headphones on Max and play her favorite song: Running Up That Hill, by Kate Bush.

When viewing the end-credits I didn't see any attribution to Kate Bush or any other music artists. I replayed the end-credits several times,and even though they flash rather quickly, I still didn't see attribution.

Did I somehow miss them? If not, why would the series creators not credit music artists?

Yes, of course, the information can be found elsewhere on the internet, but my question concerns why a successful and prominent show deviates from standard practice.

Comment: It's not always "standard" practice to credit music artists in TV shows. Credits take a lot of time and eat into ad revenue. In the end it depends on the rights being purchased and the deal done on behalf of the artist.

Comment: Movies tend to credit 'used songs' from elsewhere than the acredited incidental music composer. TV shows rarely do. As far as I'm aware there is no legal compunction, so long as the relevant rights are negotiated & paid. This would apply to both incidental and feature music [defined as "the audience can hear it", or "the characters can hear it"]

Comment: Just seems odd that a vast array of minor craftspersons are credited (in flashes) but not major music artists.

After I posted this, I watched the following episode where Ricky Nelson's, Travellin' Man was used, and timed perfectly with the lyric "Alaska" as a small plane carrying Joyce and Murray fly out of Alaska. It was a nice creative touch, and easy to miss. No credit.

Just seems baffling that a major creative endeavor like Stranger Things doesn't publicly acknowledge the music artists who play a direct role in making episodes memorable. Oh well...